# Python Google Slides API How to insert a text with hyperlink?

Tags: python, google-slides-api

I have looked through the documentation of Google Slides API, but I can't seem to find the section where you can insert a text with hyperlink. I am using python for integrating the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 methods to add links to a Google Slide, you can use [TextStyle](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/text#textstyle) which is under the `Text` for `presentations.pages` or you can use [UpdateTextStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updatetextstylerequest) under the Method: `presentations.batchUpdate`.

Here is a sample using `UpdateTextStyleRequest`, I first create a shape `textbox`, inserted the text `New URL link added!`, and update the style to hyperlink for the words `URL link`:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations']

# The ID of the presentation 
PRESENTATION_ID = 'SlideID'


def main():
   
    creds = None
    
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)

    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('slides', 'v1', credentials=creds
        element_id = 'MyTextBox_10'
        page_id = 'g1e436298788_0_0'
        pt = {
            'magnitude': 200,
            'unit': 'PT'
        }
        requests = [
            {
                'createShape': {
                    'objectId': element_id,
                    'shapeType': 'TEXT_BOX',
                    'elementProperties': {
                        'pageObjectId': page_id,
                        'size': {
                            'height': pt,
                            'width': pt
                        },
                        'transform': {
                            'scaleX': 1,
                            'scaleY': 1,
                            'translateX': 50,
                            'translateY': 100,
                            'unit': 'PT'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            # Insert text into the box, using the supplied element ID.
            {
                'insertText': {
                    'objectId': element_id,
                    'insertionIndex': 0,
                    'text': 'New URL link added!'
                }
            },

            # Insert the URL for in the speficy range.
            {
                'updateTextStyle': {
                    'objectId': element_id,
                    'textRange': {
                        'type': 'FIXED_RANGE',
                        'startIndex': 4,
                        'endIndex': 12
                    },
                    'style': {
                        'link': {
                            'url': 'www.google.com'
                        }
                    },
                    'fields': 'link'
                }
            }
            

        ]

        # Execute the request.
        body = {
            'requests': requests
        }
        response = service.presentations() \
            .batchUpdate(presentationId=PRESENTATION_ID, body=body).execute()
        create_shape_response = response.get('replies')[0].get('createShape')
        print(f"Created textbox with ID:"
              f"{(create_shape_response.get('objectId'))}")

    except HttpError as err:
        print(err)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And it'll look like this:

[image: hyperlink]

You can also review the following Google guide [Editing and Styling Text](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/guides/styling#python)